How to derive the real marginal cost index in Blanco, Boar, Jones and Midrigan (2024) working paper?
I was hoping someone could explain to me how Blanco, Boar, Callum and Midrigan (algebraically) derived the real marginal cost index for sector s in their recent working paper "Non-linear inflation dynamics in menu cost economies". More precisely, the index I am refering to is the following (page 13 in the paper):
$a_t(s) = \frac{W_t}{P_t(s) y_t(s)} \left(\frac{y_t(s)}{e_t(s)}\right)^{\frac{1}{\eta}}$
The paper's link is the following link: https://drive.google.com/file/d/13jTBmKreEcX1BbBt2FipJ97qVNcHRz5i/view
Thank you very much in advance!
